# не возможно получить изображение

Tags: moysklad-json-api

Ниже лог заголовков на получение изображения из сервиса МойСклад.
В конце лога, видно что почему-то возвращается ошибка 403. Это происходит только с одного сервера (87.236.16.3). Вместо изображения получаем xml:

`AccessDenied`Access Denied.tx2749650e362c463f91771-005ca5cc36

Запрос от нас:

> GET /api/remap/1.1/download/ea25773a-eca9-4fee-b0a4-78462ad41172? HTTP/1.1
>   Host: online.moysklad.ru
>   Accept: /
>   Authorization:Basic ==

Ответ от вас:
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Location: https://storage.files.mo01.cloud.servers.com:8080/v1/SERVERSCOM_2ce3101fed274bd6b24d2124be063f47/image-prod/image/e81b3204-ee5d-11e8-9109-f8fc00006da0/goodimage/ea25773a-eca9-4fee-b0a4-78462ad41172?temp_url_sig=90afd7550b3efc00701c268e3587826a10288028&temp_url_expires=1554375098&filename=5D3_8591.jpg

Перенаправление:

> GET /v1/SERVERSCOM_2ce3101fed274bd6b24d2124be063f47/image-prod/image/e81b3204-ee5d-11e8-9109-f8fc00006da0/goodimage/ea25773a-eca9-4fee-b0a4-78462ad41172?temp_url_sig=90afd7550b3efc00701c268e3587826a10288028&temp_url_expires=1554375098&filename=5D3_8591.jpg HTTP/1.1
>   Host: storage.files.mo01.cloud.servers.com:8080
>   Accept: /
>   Authorization:Basic ==

Ответ от вас:
< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden

Видно, что при первом запросе авторизация проходит нормально, осуществляется перенаправление с теми же учетными данными, на которое получаем запрет 403.

Полный Лог заголовков:

```
* Trying 88.212.252.4...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to online.moysklad.ru (88.212.252.4) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
* CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* NPN, negotiated HTTP1.1
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
* subject: C=RU; L=Moscow; O=LLC LogneX; OU=job; CN=*.moysklad.ru
* start date: May 10 00:00:00 2018 GMT
* expire date: Sep 11 12:00:00 2019 GMT
* subjectAltName: host "online.moysklad.ru" matched cert's "*.moysklad.ru"
* issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; OU=www.digicert.com; CN=GeoTrust RSA CA 2018
* SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /api/remap/1.1/download/ea25773a-eca9-4fee-b0a4-78462ad41172? HTTP/1.1
Host: online.moysklad.ru
Accept: /
Authorization:Basic ==

< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Server: nginx/1.10.3
< Date: Thu, 04 Apr 2019 10:50:38 GMT
< Content-Length: 0
< Connection: close
< Cache-Control: max-age=31536000, public
< Location: https://storage.files.mo01.cloud.servers.com:8080/v1/SERVERSCOM_2ce3101fed274bd6b24d2124be063f47/image-prod/image/e81b3204-ee5d-11e8-9109-f8fc00006da0/goodimage/ea25773a-eca9-4fee-b0a4-78462ad41172?temp_url_sig=90afd7550b3efc00701c268e3587826a10288028&temp_url_expires=1554375098&filename=5D3_8591.jpg
<
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Closing connection 0
* Issue another request to this URL: 'https://storage.files.mo01.cloud.servers.com:8080/v1/SERVERSCOM_2ce3101fed274bd6b24d2124be063f47/image-prod/image/e81b3204-ee5d-11e8-9109-f8fc00006da0/goodimage/ea25773a-eca9-4fee-b0a4-78462ad41172?temp_url_sig=90afd7550b3efc00701c268e3587826a10288028&temp_url_expires=1554375098&filename=5D3_8591.jpg'
* Trying 188.42.211.42...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to storage.files.mo01.cloud.servers.com (188.42.211.42) port 8080 (#1)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
* CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
* subject: OU=Domain Control Validated; OU=EssentialSSL Wildcard; CN=*.files.mo01.cloud.servers.com
* start date: Jan 23 00:00:00 2018 GMT
* expire date: Jan 25 23:59:59 2020 GMT
* subjectAltName: host "storage.files.mo01.cloud.servers.com" matched cert's "*.files.mo01.cloud.servers.com"
* issuer: C=GB; ST=Greater Manchester; L=Salford; O=COMODO CA Limited; CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
* SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /v1/SERVERSCOM_2ce3101fed274bd6b24d2124be063f47/image-prod/image/e81b3204-ee5d-11e8-9109-f8fc00006da0/goodimage/ea25773a-eca9-4fee-b0a4-78462ad41172?temp_url_sig=90afd7550b3efc00701c268e3587826a10288028&temp_url_expires=1554375098&filename=5D3_8591.jpg HTTP/1.1
Host: storage.files.mo01.cloud.servers.com:8080
Accept: /
Authorization:Basic ==

< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
< Date: Thu, 04 Apr 2019 10:50:38 GMT
< Content-Type: application/xml
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< X-Amz-Id-2: tx176109a2683f4d0281aae-005ca5e17e
< X-Amz-Request-Id: tx176109a2683f4d0281aae-005ca5e17e
< X-Trans-Id: tx176109a2683f4d0281aae-005ca5e17e
<
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Connection #1 to host storage.files.mo01.cloud.servers.com left intact
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После перенаправления не нужно использовать авторизацию.